# How to write a shell script for installation of Linkerd using CI/CD jobs

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, linkerd

shell script to automate the installation of linkerd using CI/CD jobs in AKS cluster

I have tried writing the script but need clear picture on that scripting

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.